# Docker and Node: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open "package.json"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I have the files

### docker-compose.yml

```
...
  example:
    build: 
      context: ./example
    ports:
      - 3300:3000
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ../example/:/var/www
    container_name: example
...
```

### ./example/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN npm install -g react-scripts

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I run

```
docker-compose build
```

Get this error

```
...
npm ERR! path /var/www/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

But if I comment on the `#RUN npm install`, the script sees package.json and "npm start" working, but I get error, because there are  no node_modules

Where are the contents of the mounted folder, when "npm install"?

Comment: Volume mounts don't happen until after the image build.  If you want to work on local code, I'd suggest a host Node as a more appropriate and much simpler tool than Docker.  You need to `COPY` the `package.json` and other source code into your image before you `RUN npm ci`; and then you should remove the `volumes:` mounts to avoid overwriting that code when you run the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze removing `volumes:` mounts is working, but now nodemon doesn't detect changes

Comment: Right, a Docker container is an isolated environment and an image contains an immutable copy of the application.  You need to run Nodemon in your host-based Javascript development environment, before you start building Docker images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze), he gave food for the mind.

After several decisions, the best thing for me is the following

### docker-compose.yml

```
...
  example:
    build: 
      context: ./example
    ports:
      - 3300:3000
    volumes:
      - ./example/:/var/www
    container_name: example
...
```

### ./example/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN npm install -g react-scripts

RUN chown -Rh node:node /var/www

USER node

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "npm install && npm run start" ]
```

This solution is great for development.
The user `node` will help you with the rights of host<->guest

The folder `node_modules` will be accessible from the host and synchronize host<->guest